# How can I find out weapons and their stats?

Tags: apex-legends

There are a lot of weapons in *Apex Legends* and it can be a bit overwhelming trying to figure out which weapon is better than another, and when I should swap my currently equipped weapon with a new one I just found. It would be great if I knew what the stats of these weapons were (Damage, RPM, Ammo type etc.) so I could better make these decisions.

**How can I find out the stats for all of the in-game weapons?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Apex Legends Gun Stats [Balance Update 3/06/2019]

#### Assault Rifles

```
Assault Rifles              Havoc           VK-47 Flatline  Hemlock Burst   R-301 Carbine
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ammo                        Energy          Heavy           Heavy           Light
Mag Size                    25              20              18              18
Partial / Full Reload (s)   3.20/3.20       2.40/3.10       2.40/2.80       2.40/3.20
DPS                         201.6           160             108             189
Body/Head/Leg Dmg           18/36/13.5      16/32/12        18/36/13.5      14/28/10.5
Fire Rate (per sec)         11.2            10              15 (6)          13.5
Attachments                 3               3               4               4
Modes                       Single,Auto     Single,Auto     Single,Burst(3) Single,Auto
Projectile Speed            30500           26000           27500           29000
Draw Time                   0.60s           0.60s           0.60s           0.60s
ADS Movement Speed          50%             50%             50%             50%
```

#### SMGs

```
SMGs                        Alternator SMG  R-99            Prowler Burst PDW
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ammo                        Light           Light           Heavy
Mag Size                    16              18              20
Partial / Full Reload (s)   1.90/2.23       1.80/2.45       2.00/2.60
DPS                         130             216             122.78
Body/Head/Leg Dmg           13/19/10.4      12/18/9.6       14/21/11.2
Fire Rate (per sec)         10              18              20 (8.77)
Attachments                 4               4               4
Modes                       Auto            Auto            Burst(5), Auto
Projectile Speed            19500           21000           18000
Draw Time                   0.35s           0.35s           0.35s
ADS Movement Speed          86%             86%             86%
```

#### Light Machine Guns

```
Light Machine Guns          Devotion        M600 Spitfire   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ammo                        Energy          Heavy
Mag Size                    44              30
Partial / Full Reload (s)   2.80/3.63       2.80/3.33
DPS                         255             180
Body/Head/Leg Dmg           17/34/12.75     20/40/16
Fire Rate (per sec)         15 (max)        9
Attachments                 4               4
Modes                       Auto (Windup)   Auto
Projectile Speed            33500           27500
Draw Time                   0.35s           0.35s
ADS Movement Speed          41%             41%
```

#### Sniper Rifles

```
Sniper Rifles               G7 Scout        Longbow DMR     Triple Take     Kraber .50 CAL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ammo                        Light           Heavy           Energy          Unique
Mag Size                    10              5               5               4
Partial / Full Reload (s)   2.40/3.00       2.66/3.66       2.60/3.40       3.20/4.30
DPS                         135             66              86.25           150
Body/Head/Leg Dmg           30/60/21.75     55/110/39.875   23/46/16.675    125/250/90.625
Fire Rate (per sec)         4.5             1.2             1.25            1.2
Attachments                 4               5               3               0
Modes                       Single          Single          Single (3 spr.) Single
Projectile Speed            31500           30500           32000           29500
Draw Time                   0.60s           0.90s           0.90s           1.20s
ADS Movement Speed          36%             36%             36%             36%
```

#### Shotguns

```
Shotguns                    EVA-8 Auto      Peacekeeper     Mozambique      Mastiff
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ammo                        Shotgun         Shotgun         Shotgun         Unique
Mag Size                    8               6               3               4
Partial / Full Reload (s)   2.75/3.00       2.50/3.50       2.10/2.60       1.03/1.70
DPS                         126             106.7           99              187.2
Body/Head/Leg Dmg           7/10/5.6        10/15/8         15/22/13.5      18/36/18
(All Bullets)               (63/90/50.4)    (110/165/88)    (45/66/40.5)    (144/288/144)
Fire Rate (per sec)         2               0.97            2.2             1.3
Attachments                 2               3               2               0
Modes                       Auto            Single          Auto            Single
Projectile Speed            16000           16000           10000           12000
Draw Time                   0.45s           0.45s           0.45s           0.45s
ADS Movement Speed          91%             91%             100%             91%
```

#### Pistols

```
Pistols                     P2020           RE 45 Auto      Wingman
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ammo                        Light           Light           Heavy
Mag Size                    10              15              6
Partial / Full Reload (s)   1.25/1.25       1.74/2.12       2.10/2.10
DPS                         102             143             117
Body/Head/Leg Dmg           12/18/10.8      11/16/9.9       45/90/40.5
Fire Rate (per sec)         8.5             13              2.6
Attachments                 2               3               3
Modes                       Single          Auto            Single
Projectile Speed            18500           19500           18000
Draw Time                   0.25s           0.25s           0.25s
ADS Movement Speed          100%            95%             100%
```

All stats are copied from the excellent RPS write up [here](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2019/03/13/apex-legends-guns-weapons-balance-update-best-guns-weapon-stats-weapon-tier-list/). The linked guide also contains weapon spread images and recommendations for new players.